# unrecognized selector sent to instance with UILabel in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, unrecognized-selector

I am writing an app in Swift that keeps track of a baseball game. I have over 20 labels I need to edit. I keep getting an "unrecognized selector sent to instance" error. I have set breakpoints on every UILabel outlet, and it crashes after it goes around the second time on away2nd. Here is my class for the app:

```
var home_scores = [Int]()
var away_scores = [Int]()
var player_list = [String]()
var inning = 1
var topInning = true
var Strikes = 0
var balls = 0
var outs = 0
//Outlets for most variable text
@IBOutlet var PlayerList: UITableView!
@IBOutlet var StrikesText: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var BallsText: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var OutsText: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var InningText: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var InnSideText: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var BatterName: UILabel!

//Outlets for score text... its a lot of outlets
//away
@IBOutlet var away1st: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var away2nd: UILabel! //crashes after a breakpoint here
@IBOutlet var away3rd: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var away4th: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var away5th: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var away6th: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var away7th: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var away8th: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var away9th: UILabel!
//home
@IBOutlet var home1st: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var home2nd: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var home3rd: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var home4th: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var home5th: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var home6th: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var home7th: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var home8th: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var home9th: UILabel!

func displayScores() {
    away1st.text = String(away_scores[0])
    away2nd.text = String(away_scores[1])
    away3rd.text = String(away_scores[2])
    away4th.text = String(away_scores[3])
    away5th.text = String(away_scores[4])
    away6th.text = String(away_scores[5])
    away7th.text = String(away_scores[6])
    away8th.text = String(away_scores[7])
    away9th.text = String(away_scores[8])
    home1st.text = String(home_scores[0])
    home2nd.text = String(home_scores[1])
    home3rd.text = String(home_scores[2])
    home4th.text = String(home_scores[3])
    home5th.text = String(home_scores[4])
    home6th.text = String(home_scores[5])
    home7th.text = String(home_scores[6])
    home8th.text = String(home_scores[7])
    home9th.text = String(home_scores[8])
}
@IBAction func hitStrike() {
    Strikes += 1
}
```

This is the error:

```
2016-11-10 14:00:30.463 Base Tracker iPad[5992:325296] -[UILabel longLongValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fcaf1601c90
Process 5992 resuming
2016-11-10 14:00:30.538 Base Tracker iPad[5992:325296] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UILabel longLongValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fcaf1601c90'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105ab534b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000102dc921e objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105b24f34 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105a3ac15 ___forwarding___ + 1013
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105a3a798 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   Foundation                          0x0000000102953faf _NSSetLongLongValueForKeyWithMethod + 63
    6   Foundation                          0x00000001028d926f -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 291
    7   UIKit                               0x00000001034324ef -[UIViewController setValue:forKey:] + 88
    8   UIKit                               0x00000001036a679e -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 109
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105a5a590 -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 256
    10  UIKit                               0x00000001036a5122 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1867
    11  UIKit                               0x0000000103438c21 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 386
    12  UIKit                               0x0000000103439543 -[UIViewController loadView] + 177
    13  UIKit                               0x0000000103439878 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 201
    14  UIKit                               0x000000010343a0cc -[UIViewController view] + 27
    15  UIKit                               0x0000000103acd4be -[UIPageViewController _setViewControllers:withScrollInDirection:animated:completion:] + 591
    16  UIKit                               0x0000000103acd744 -[UIPageViewController setViewControllers:direction:animated:completion:] + 269
    17  Base Tracker iPad                   0x00000001027d0531 _TFC17Base_Tracker_iPad20MyPageViewController11viewDidLoadfT_T_ + 2609
    18  Base Tracker iPad                   0x00000001027d07f2 _TToFC17Base_Tracker_iPad20MyPageViewController11viewDidLoadfT_T_ + 34
    19  UIKit                               0x0000000103439c99 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 1258
    20  UIKit                               0x000000010343a0cc -[UIViewController view] + 27
    21  UIKit                               0x0000000103d04bce __67-[UIStoryboardEmbedSegueTemplate newDefaultPerformHandlerForSegue:]_block_invoke + 496
    22  UIKit                               0x0000000103a72fbd -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate _performWithDestinationViewController:sender:] + 447
    23  UIKit                               0x0000000103a72dcd -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate _perform:] + 82
    24  UIKit                               0x0000000103a7308f -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate perform:] + 156
    25  UIKit                               0x0000000103439a7e -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 719
    26  UIKit                               0x000000010343a0cc -[UIViewController view] + 27
    27  UIKit                               0x0000000103303c51 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 71
    28  UIKit                               0x00000001033043a2 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 293
    29  UIKit                               0x0000000103317cb5 -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 42
    30  UIKit                               0x0000000103290c89 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 4818
    31  UIKit                               0x0000000103296de9 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1731
    32  UIKit                               0x0000000103293f69 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 188
    33  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000107179723 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 24
    34  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010717959c -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 189
    35  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000107179925 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 45
    36  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105a5a311 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    37  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105a3f59c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    38  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105a3ea86 __CFRunLoopRun + 918
    39  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105a3e494 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
    40  UIKit                               0x00000001032927e6 -[UIApplication _run] + 434
    41  UIKit                               0x0000000103298964 UIApplicationMain + 159
    42  Base Tracker iPad                   0x00000001027d79bf main + 111
    43  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001069e268d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

What is causing the error? I have seen that it can be caused by reused memory, but this is just when the app is loading.

Comment: Can you post the whole error message? Which selector exactly is sent to the UILabel?

Comment: You should probably be using a collection view

Comment: Also, my guess is one of your labels isn't properly connected to your storboard/nib

Comment: @PEEJWEEJ If it was not connected, it would crash because of forced unwrapping of nil

Comment: @alexburtnik Good point. When is the being called? are you sure the view is loaded?

Comment: @JackMacWindows: Try to set Exception breakpoint. Breakpoints tab in Xcode -> + button on the bottom left -> Add Exception breakpoint. Then reproduce the crash and tell us which line is causing the crash

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127839/discussion-between-alexburtnik-and-peejweej).

Comment: Make sure score array not having nill value .If post a sample of score array it will be helpful to debug

Answer (score 2):

This can happen if one of your label in the storyboard/nib file was connected in your view controller and later on the variable in the view controller corresponding to that label's connection was removed. This could leave a dangling reference for the label in the storyboard/nib file.

I would say check each any every UI elements in the storyboard/nib file and see if there are any variable names which you do not have referenced inside your corresponding view controller.

Comment: I have checked all my connections, and I have no unlinked connections happening. The code is pretty much from template.

Comment: Thank-you. This answer resolved the error for me for the situation described. I had copied the IBOutlet from another view controller which was properly connected to a storyboard, but failed to connect the label to the new storyboard. The label's IBOutlet looked like it was connected in the new view controller. Once the missing storyboard connection was added, all was good.